# How to get `hash -d` shortcut path of a full path in ZSH?

Tags: zsh

For example, if I set this in ZSH,

```bsh
hash -d x=/a/b/c
```

then I can get the path `/a/b/c/d` by using `~x/d`.

Reversely, how can I get the string `~x/d` from path `/a/b/c/d`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Bad bot. This question is perfectly clear to anyone using [tag:zsh].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to print the shortcut, you can do

```bash
% print -D /a/b/c/d
~x/d
```

See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print

If you need access to the shortcut in a script, use

```bash
${(D):-/a/b/c/d}
```

See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags